# electron-packager Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: electron

When running my app directly with electron

```
electron .
```

everything works fine, but when packaging the app with electron-packager and running it, i get the error

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

in the code

```
mainWindow.loadURL(`${__dirname}/../build/index.html`)
```

any help??

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the BrowserWindow' options:

```
 new BrowserWindow({
   webPreferences: {
   webSecurity: false
 }
})
```

by adding

```
webPreferences: {
 webSecurity: false
}
```

it stops securing local access and your file becomes accessible
If window's url points to a remote source, like http://..., browser will not allow to load local resource, unless you set the options above.

Comment: I had this same problem and this solved it for me. Amazing, so cool to see it install and run perfectly!! Thank you!! :-D

Comment: happy to help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of detail missing from this request.  I would always use `path.resolve` to access your local files rather than the interpolation you are using. For example, if you are setting up electron with its normal options, I'd do something like:

```
    var path = require('path');

    var iconPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/program.ico');
    const appIcon = new Tray(iconPath);
    mainWindow = new Window({
        width: 1280,
        height: 1024,
        autoHideMenuBar: false,
        useContentSize: true,
        resizable: true,
        icon: iconPath });

    var indexPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html');
    mainWindow.loadURL(indexPath);
```

That said, my guess is that your `../build/index.html` path is actually not the place your files are at. This error happens when you don't copy your distribution to the location you think you are copying it (or the copy fails).